# Tablature notation meaning

Tags: theory, piano, notation, tablature, sonata

[image: Alfred Schnittke's Piano Sonata No.3]

What is that tablature symbol in the second bar of Alfred Schnittke's piano sonata no.3 ?

Comment: It's not tablature, and Tim's answer is correct.

Comment: As an aside - why would the Bb be more appropriate than A# in the first bar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is it's an F♯ note in the bass, which lasts the whole bar - equivalent to four minims - a breve.

Breve translated means *short* - even though it's the longest duration note in use now. There was a much longer one, 2 or sometimes 3 times as long as the breve, called funnily enough, the **longa**. Makes me wonder about *sustain* on notes in days gone by...

Comment: Is it really a guess?

Comment: Thanks a lot, as I use musescore it's different in design also I know a breve but I never used before, thanks for your answer

Comment: @phoog - at time of writing - yes! Since found it in my 'bible' - can't see it in Dolmetsch though. Very little need for a breve these days, write a slower tempo instead !

Comment: @SanjaiS, Tim: oh, I see.  I'd forgotten about the modern form of breve formed by adding vertical lines to the whole note (the form that I found when I searched Dolmetsch online).  The form seen here was in use through the 19th century at least, probably to the middle of the 20th.  I suppose musescore has a way of using that form if you really want to.

Comment: Also see the Wikipedia redirect https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Breve_(music).

Comment: @phoog - knowing what some sign is called already makes looking things up much easier! It's when you don't know the name, it's hard.

Comment: Of course.  But even knowing the name I was unable to find it in Dolmetsch online, though I didn't try for more than a minute or two.

Comment: @phoog - so only a breve search, then?

Comment: It's a breve. I've seen two longer notes; a longa which (as mentioned) is 2 or 3 times a breve and a maxima which is 2 or three times a longa. Thus using the usual (if one assumes breves and demisemihemidemisemiquavers are not too unusual) gives a range of 2048 is note lengths.